# Аналог JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK

Tags: php, json

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть ли какой-нибудь аналог вот такой команды:

```
echo json_encode($values, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

которая бы работала на PHP версии 5.2?

Comment: Почему вы не хотите перед упаковкой ответа задать типы элементам $values?

Comment: @Kirill Korushkin, Вы не могли бы на каком нибудь очень коротком и простом примере показать, что Вы иметее в виду?

Answer (score -1):

Можно и самому привести к числам, используя регулярные выражения и [preg_replace()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-replace.php):

```
$json = json_encode($values);
$numeric_json = preg_replace('/\\"(\\d+)\\"(\\,|\\})/', '$1$2', $json );
```

Comment: спасибо, попробывал, но результаты не эквивалентны.

Comment: А в чем именно различия? Добавь, пожалуйста пример того, что есть на выводе и что нужно получить.